# When did Shakyamuni became buddha?

Tags: the-buddha, enlightenment, doubt

We know Shakyamuni was a prince and had all the lavish life a prince should have. He was isolated from every pain and suffering as we are told. As he traveled countryside he began to feel pain and suffering in others and witnessed death. He could have been ignorant or at most have donated some of his wealth to the commoners, but he didn't. He left the life he had, and set out to seek the ultimate truth of life. At Gaya, he meditated and got enlightened and became a buddha as most of us are told.

OK, above mentioned is what we all know. Problem is, what if he had not decided to leave the prince-hood? What if he didn't have that curiosity? **Isn't the first step he took by leaving his old life behind, a sign of becoming buddha?** I believe that step as the sprout of enlightenment.

Please, explain if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he left the lay life, he didn't have any attainment(Nibbana) yet. 
Thinking to leave the lay life is called Nekkhamma Sankappa. It's a part of [Samma Sankappa](http://www.vipassana.com/resources/8fp3.php), the right thought of the noble eight fold path.

Even ordinary people can get Nekkhamma thoughts from time to time. But those are often not strong enough to make them give up the lay life.

The common understanding is that the Buddha attained all stages of enlightenment under the Bodhi tree on the same morning he became the Buddha.

Comment: Considering your answer, "the right thought of the noble eight fold path", I can consider the step Shakyamuni took by leaving his lavish life, as a first step towards becoming buddha. That justified my thought.

Comment: If you meant in that sense, the first step would be when he determined to become a Buddha in the future many eons ago.

Comment: Did Shakyamuni really decide to become Buddha in his previous life?

Comment: Yes, indeed! http://www.abuddhistlibrary.com/Buddhism/F-%20Miscellaneous/Miscellaneous%20Buddhism/The%20Way%20of%20the%20Bodhisattva/The%20Way%20of%20Bodhisattva.htm

Comment: Ok, it seems every Buddha predict future Buddha, on time when people forget Dharma completely. Is it the time now for Maitri Buddha, to reincarnate, as I can feel people not believing anymore on the Dharma?

Comment: No, the Maithree Buddha won't appear for a long time. People forget about the Dhamma when the Buddha Sasana ends in another 2500 years. Even after that, you have to wait until the average human lifespan is about 80000 years for Maithree Buddha to appear.

Answer (score 1):

[**unconfirmed, proceed with caution**] *since in his previous lives he already was a bodhisatta and so a noble disciple, becoming awakened was only a matter of time since according to the Dhamma after attainment of the sotapatti noble level (the 1st of the four) nibbana is to be attained within 7 lives at the most.*

*thus the Buddha was predestined to become one. even he himself couldn't change that. it's only that all his previous practice and wholesome kamma ripened in that particular life 2500 years ago*

---

until the awakening he was not a buddha, but an unawakened bodhisatta

> before my Awakening, when I was an unawakened bodhisatta

*Ariyapariyesana sutta (MN 26) by [Ven Thanissaro Bhikkhu](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.026.than.html)*

Comment: QUOTE: He didn't attain Sotapanna in a previous life. It all happened under the Bodhi tree sequentially in the same night/morning – Sankha Kulathantille 28 mins ago~~~~~

RESPONSE: @Sankha Kulathantille this is an interesting question which requires further research, unless i'm referred to doctrinal sources confirming that explicitly and unequivocally

Comment: It's technically impossible for him to be a Sothapanna and toture himself for 6 years in search of Nibbana. Because once you become Sothapanna you give up sīlabbata-parāmāsa. Which means he knows that the noble eight fold path is the only way to attain Nibbana.

Comment: i'm not sure that his austerities fall into the category of sīlabbata-parāmāsa, i'm not saying i disagree, but still in doubt

Comment: It does! He wasn't torturing himself out of boredom. He believed it would lead to end of suffering.

Comment: Isn't the person who became bodhisatta, not supposed to rebirth again, unless he wishes to?

Comment: @kiran No! Bodhisatta just means the being who is working towards the Buddhahood. Until he becomes the Buddha he is reborn due to craving.

Comment: A Bodhisatta is always a wording, never an ariyan, such is not possible. Some maybe useful questions and answers by Ven. Pa-Auk Tawya Sayadaw: [Bodhisatta Path Answers of question](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,900.msg3069.html#msg3069). Atma would even go further and say that a Bodhisatta can even not be a member of Sangha on the conventional level, since to which Dhamma, primary would he take refugee, which Buddha would he take as refuge, which Sangha? A Bodhisatta is that what the words meaning is: A being searching for the path to liberation, & not like mostly thought a Buddha to be.

Comment: what i really am unsure of is that an ariyan in the next life behaves as one right from the birthday, since it could be that they need some time to kind of subconsciously 'recall' their attainment, to adjust, for the sankharas which define their aryian achievement to become active and start affecting their further life

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Sankhara don't define Maggapala. Nibbana is unconditioned. Also, once your fetters are annihilated, rebirth can't make them return. It's a permanent change. A Sothapanna being when reborn as human learns that the name given to a person like him is 'Sothapanna'. He doesn't need to reacquire it.